Why is a global thread_local object get deleted during a Qt ui initialization?
I'm writing a QT program with a lot of database queries.
The QSqlDatabase is not thread safe as the documents states.
So I wrote a simple thread_local QSqlDatabase to maintain a database connection per thread.
class Database
{
public:
    static Database& Database::get()
    {
        thread_local static Database database;
        return database;
    }

    Database::~Database()
    {
    
        if (close()) {
            QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(this->dbname);
        }
    }
private:
    Database::Database() {
        this->dbname ="my_db_" + QString::number((quint64)QThread::currentThread(), 16);
        if(QSqlDatabase::contains(this->dbname))
            this->db = QSqlDatabase::database(this->dbname);
        else {
            this->db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", this->dbname);
            this->db.setDatabaseName(this->filename);
            this->db.setPassword(this->password);
        }
        open();
    }
    private:
        QSqlDatabase db;
        QString dbname;
        static QString filename;
        static QString password;
};

I query the database in main(), before MainWindow's creation.
But during MainWindow's creation, the database destructor is called, and the database connection is closed and removed.
Afer that (in the ui initialization and any ui operations afterwards), all the database queries fail.
I notice that the ui's thread id and the main()'s thread id are exactly the same, to me they are the same thread.
I do not understand why the Datatbase object destructor is called in between (it seems like some old thread is destroyed, and some new thread is created with exactly the same thread id?).
If I just comment out the close and removeDatabase in the destructor, and everything works fine.
What is the exact reason for this?
Thanks.

Why such a hack in the first place? Simply use QSqlDatabase::addDatabase() and QSqlDatabase::database() in the first place. Also you don't show the usage of your class so we don't see where the destructor is called -> please provide a minimal, compilable example or even better - use the class Qt provided by you as nothing above is needed at all.

The thread_local object gets destroyed when the thread that created it dies.

This is not the minimum reproducible sample. But I can see a  half baked thread singleton pattern. I see a possibility for violation of rule 350; because Database has a none-trivial destructor that eventually releases the database handles. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

On first glance, there appears to be no reason for the thread_local to be destroyed. Did you try setting a breakpoint on the destructor -- maybe the stacktrace can provide an idea what might be going on? Also, I just googled QSqlDatabase and learned that it can be copied, and I'm assuming QString can be copied anyway, so maybe you're making a copy somewhere and you're not even seeing the destructor call on the thread_local but on the copy...

At a guess you have a auto db = Database::get() somewhere which creates a copy, you should make your class non-copyable

Alan may be on to something, but we can't know for sure unless you show us a [mre].

@ChristianStieber Me bad... I don't know how, but I missed that.
